# Get maximum size of the control without maximizing it, windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which contains picturebox (Anchor is set as Left, Right, Top and Bottom) and some other controls,I would like to know is there anyway to get the size of the picturebox when the form is maximized without maximising the form,

[I have to crop an image based on picturebox's maximum size]

Comment: You'd have to use the size of the screen and use some calculations, i.e. width of screen - (2 * width of border), etc. etc. in order to figure out the maximum size the picturebox can be without actually making it maximised.

Comment: @FizzBuzz, I think when the form is maximized other controls also get maximized, so, is there any ways to predict those :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve the problem. 
1. Move to WPF. (Windows Forms is becoming deprecated.)
2. Use reflection to get the properties of the picturebox during runtime. 
Try something like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
private PictureBox DoSomethingWithProperties(PictureBox picturebox)
{
    Type pictureboxType = picturebox.GetType();
    PictureBox instance = (PictureBox)Activator.CreateInstance(pictureboxType)
    // The above code is only used to create an instance of the picturebox type. 
    // This will enable modification/changes to the picturebox property values during runtime via late-binding.
    PropertyInfo DefaultSize= instance.GetType().GetProperty("DefaultSize", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    PropertyInfo ClientSize= instance.GetType().GetProperty("ClientSize", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    PropertyInfo DefaultMaximumSize= instance.GetType().GetProperty("DefaultMaximumSize", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: What kind of `using` statement are you using? Is that new feature of `C# 6.0`?